# Accessing objects that aren't bound to a variable in Python

Tags: python, object, python-multithreading

I've been learning to program with Python on and off for a while now, and my current project is a download manager with a GUI written in wxPython. I have DownloadThreads, inheriting from threading.Thread, that I instantiate a varying amount of:

```
for i in xrange(self.thread_count):
    DownloadThread(self.queue, self.status, self.save_dir, i).start()
```

Because the number of threads I'm going to be creating isn't fixed, I can't assign the `DownloadThread` objects to variables, so I can't see how to access their methods, such as `x.isAlive()`. I thought about dynamically creating variables, but something about this seems like a really bad idea. How would I go about accessing these "anonymous" objects (terminology?), or am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks for reading, apologies if this is really simple / obvious.

Comment: To access an object you have to bind them, it's the same in every language I know. Anonymous things are for onetime use and throw away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to keep all your threads in a list:

```
self.threads = []
for i in xrange(self.thread_count):
    self.threads.append(DownloadThread(self.queue, self.status, self.save_dir, i))
    self.threads[i].start()
```

Comment: I don't really feel the list comprehension makes this clearer.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is the sort of thing I was after.

Comment: @Lattyware ok, used *regular* iteration syntax

Comment: @Lattyware I would probably factor the 'create a thread and start it' part into a separate function, and then use a list comprehension that calls the helper.

Comment: I generally see list comps as the clearest way to construct a list, but in this case, it's more an operation, with a list being made as a side-effect. It may just be me, but I prefer to keep this kind of thing in a regular loop - generally because I find it clearer and so I can add more code when needed. Of course, having it in a function in a list comp also allows for that.